# Calling an EJB client from node

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, call

As you will surely notice, i'm quite new to EJB and Wildfly, but i'm trying my best to understand, doing some experiments. The problem is, i want to run a simple EJB (a stateful counter), deployed in Wildfly (from a jar), from another client node. To do so, i created 2 virtual machines using Vagrant, the first one contains Wildfly, Java and so on, and deploys the jar, while the second contains only java (and should probably contain something else), and has another jar containing the client.

This machine should be able to call the method inside the deployed ejb. I successfully called a simple war, deployed in the same way, but i need to understand how i can call this method, and the informations i found are confusing, from my point of view.

This is the client class, and this class is in the jar contained in the client:

```
package ejb.counter.client;
import ejb.counter.SessionCounter;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
public class SessionCounterClient {
    @EJB(lookup = "ejb/asw/SessionCounter")
    private static SessionCounter counter;
    public SessionCounterClient() { }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionCounterClient client = new SessionCounterClient();
        client.run();
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int i=1; i<=50; i++) {
            System.out.println( counter.getCounter() );
        }
        counter.close();
    }
}
```

So obviously the method i have to call is getCounter().
The other EJB contains the interface and its implementation, here's the implementation:

```
package ejb.counter.impl;

import ejb.counter.SessionCounter;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.ejb.Remove;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Stateful(mappedName = "ejb/asw/SessionCounter")
public class SessionCounterImpl implements SessionCounter {
    private int counter;
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        this.counter = 0;
    }
    public int getCounter() {
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }
    @Remove
    public void close() {}
}
```

Maybe i should use this informations, but i can't get how:

```
WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'SessionCounterImpl' in deployment unit 'deployment "CounterEJB.jar"' are as follows:

java:global/CounterEJB/SessionCounterImpl!ejb.counter.SessionCounter
java:app/CounterEJB/SessionCounterImpl!ejb.counter.SessionCounter
java:module/SessionCounterImpl!ejb.counter.SessionCounter
java:jboss/exported/CounterEJB/SessionCounterImpl!ejb.counter.SessionCounter
    ejb:CounterEJB/SessionCounterImpl!ejb.counter.SessionCounter?stateful
java:global/CounterEJB/SessionCounterImpl
java:app/CounterEJB/SessionCounterImpl
java:module/SessionCounterImpl
```

The result i hope to achieve is: i start the 2 virtual machines, i deploy the jar in Wildfly on the first one, i connect (using another command line) to the second, client machine, and using a script i call the EJB (executing the method in the client jar), which displays its result through the command line.
I can recreate this on a Glassfish-Payara environment, but it works in a different way, as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the SessionCounterClient is your EJB client. Ideally, the EJB client will call a method from the EJB deployed on the server. In the main method of your client code, you are calling a method "run". The implementation of the "run" method will be in the EJB.

Comment: ok so i have 2 different jars. First one contains the implementation and the run method and is deployed in the server machine, in wildfly. The second is the client and must be used from the client machine. The question is, how do i call the method in the deployed ejb? It's just a counter, so the ideal solution would be to call it using a script. I saw a script that does it on glassfish-payara, but i don't know how i'm supposed to do it with wildfly.

Comment: I edited the question, now the problem should be more comprihensible.

Comment: EJB-A is deployed on WildFly1. EJB-B is deployed in WildFly 2. EJB client is in EBJ-B which is calling "run" method from EJB-A.                                             If this is the scenario, In WildFly 1 you will need to create a outbound-socket-connection. In EJB-B you can use that socket to connect to EJB-A and then EJB-B can execute the "run" method of EJB-A.                            Let me know if it helps. I can assist you in configuring the EJB-B which containts the EJB client.